# Strange behavior in Objective-C object dealloc in ARC enabled Environment

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Problem : I am seeing some strange behavior in the order in which dealloc method is invoked on a static object after being set to nil.

To explain the problem, I have taken a class name BBSampleClass, which has two methods

```
interface BBSampleClass : NSObject
+ (BBDummyObject*)getInstance; 
+ (void)cleanUp;
@end


static BBSampleClass *sInstance = nil;
@implementation BBSampleClass

+ (void)initialize
{
    sInstance = [[BBDummyObject alloc] init];
}

+ (BBDummyObject*)getInstance
{
    return sInstance;
}

+ (void)cleanUp
{
    sInstance = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"BBSampleClass Object Dealloc");
}

@end
```

At some point in my application, If I invoke class method ***cleanUp*** in *BBSampleClass*, (which sets the static instance variable *sInstance* to *nil*), one would expect its dealloc be called immediately before executing other statements, as no other object owns sInstance at that moment.

i.e. executing these two statements

```
[BBSampleClass cleanUp]
NSLog(@"After Cleanup");
```

Should output following to console, which is Correct.

```
**2013-01-11 14:14:32.280 BBSampleCode[7781:c07] BBSampleClass Object Dealloc
```

2013-01-11 14:14:32.280 BBSampleCode[7781:c07] After Cleanup**

However, If I try to retrieve the BBSampleClass's object through its ***getInstance*** class method, like this

```
[BBSampleClass getInstance];//do something with object 
[BBSampleClass cleanUp];  
NSLog(@"After Cleanup");
```

The order of execution of NSLog statements is reversed, i.e. BBSampleClass's static object is deallocated after executing the statement ***NSLog(@"After Cleanup")*** , which is wrong.

```
 **2013-01-11 14:15:43.940 BBWebView[7811:c07] After Cleanup
2013-01-11 14:15:43.940 BBWebView[7811:c07] BBSampleClass Object Dealloc**
```

**EDIT: Solution**

Moving [BBSampleClass getInstance] into an @autoreleasepool { } block solves the issue.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your problem is. Could you rephrase it using correct terminology, complete comprehensive English sentences and a minimal code example that actually compiles?

Comment: Is there something missing in scenario2 and output2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initialize` is sent to a class before any other message, so you start with a strong reference `sTop` to your object.

*Scenario #1:*

`[BBDummyObject cleanUp]` sets `sTop = nil`. The last strong reference to the object is gone and the object is deallocated immediately.

So "Dummy Dealloc" is printed before "After Cleanup".

*Scenario #2:*

The `[BBDummyObject getInstance]` method retains the returned object `sTop` and adds it to the autorelease pool, as described in [3.2.3 Unretained return values](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values) of the Clang ARC documentation.

`[BBDummyObject cleanUp]` sets `sTop = nil`. This destroys the strong reference from `sTop` to the object and the retain count is decremented. But the retain count is still positive, therefore the object is not destroyed at this point.

Then you print "After Cleanup".

When the program leaves the scope of the current `@autoreleasepool { }`, all objects in the autorelease pool receive a `release` message. The retain count of your object is now zero and the object is released.

Therefore "Dummy Dealloc" is printed now.

A *simplified description* is: `[BBDummyObject getInstance]` creates a strong reference which is destroyed automatically when the current autorelease pool is destroyed. Therefore 
`[BBDummyObject cleanUp]` does not destroy the object immediately, and "After Cleanup" is printed before "Dummy Dealloc".

---

`getInstance` returns an unretained return value due to the ARC naming conventions. If you rename your method to `copyInstance` then it would return a (+1) retained value, which is not added to the autorelease pool. For Example:

```
BBDummyObject *obj = [BBDummyObject copyInstance]; // retain count of object is increased.
// do something with obj ...
obj = nil; // retain count is decreased immediately.
[BBDummyObject cleanUp]; // should dealloc object immediately.
```

Comment: Martin, that explains well.  Do you know any setting where I can obtain the pointer without any retain or autorelease on it? Looked into __attribute__ setting, did not find such an option..

Comment: @BharathBooshan: I have added something to my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scenario #1

[BBDummyObject cleanUp];
NSLog(@"After Cleanup");

Output #1

 Dummy Dealloc
 After Cleanup
```

This is somewhat straight :

You called cleanUp, which is setting it to `nil`. Which results to call `dealloc`.Then your `NSLog` worked.

Comment: Correct.. But add a statement '[BBSampleClass getInstance]' at first, then the order of NSLog statements change. [Please note that I have changed the class name from BBDummyObject to BBSampleClass to make it sound better]